# More complex logic with pandas loc?

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to match a column for multiple characteristics, i.e.

```
df.loc[df['col1'] == (5 or 6), 'col2'] = 5
```

How can I do this? I tried this method but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df['col1']==5) | (df['col1']==6),'col2'] = 5
```

You can also use `in` for this example, but in some cases of complex logic, using the `bitwise` operations of | (or) and & (and) are necessary.

Comment: I think `in` is more elegant here.

Comment: Agreed, but his question was about more complex logic. You can't always use `in`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.query`

```
idx  = df.query('col1 == 1.178238 or col1 == 0.144455').index
df.loc[idx, 'col2'] = 5
```

Comment: yeah, if you let me finish my post then there's no need for your comments :)