# Pandas loc with multiple keys error and TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable with idxmax()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck with getting multiple columns in pandas with loc.

```
 order_book = pd.DataFrame(client.OrderBook.OrderBook_getL2(  


            symbol='XBTUSD',
            depth = 0


        ).result()[0])
order_book.set_index(['price', 'size', 'side'], inplace= True) 
# setting multiple indexes to use loc with price size and side
```

so after that my dataframe looks like that:

```
                                id  symbol
price  size  side                     
9636.0 64    Sell  15599036400  XBTUSD
9635.5 3024  Sell  15599036450  XBTUSD
9635.0 1304  Sell  15599036500  XBTUSD
9634.5 731   Sell  15599036550  XBTUSD
9634.0 534   Sell  15599036600  XBTUSD
9633.5 1406  Sell  15599036650  XBTUSD
9633.0 32590 Sell  15599036700  XBTUSD
9632.5 67039 Buy   15599036750  XBTUSD
9632.0 194   Buy   15599036800  XBTUSD
9631.5 125   Buy   15599036850  XBTUSD
9631.0 95    Buy   15599036900  XBTUSD
9630.5 95    Buy   15599036950  XBTUSD
9630.0 65    Buy   15599037000  XBTUSD
9629.5 333   Buy   15599037050  XBTUSD
```

I was trying as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890859/pandas-loc-multiple-conditions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660672/more-complex-logic-with-pandas-loc)

```
df2 = order_book.loc[~(order_book["size"] > 50) & ~(order_book["side"] == "Buy")]
```

But im getting `KeyError: 'size'` error with `inplace = True` and with `inplace = False` im getting `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, price, side, size, symbol]
Index: []`

---

**My goal is to get as output sum of "sizes" from 'Buy'.**

1) I want to get the first price with 'Buy'. (from the example above 9632.5)

2) And after get all sizes with this price - 10. ( 9632.5 - 2 = 9630.5)

3) And get sum of that sizes (67039 + 194 + 125 + 95 + 95)

---

Questions:

1) How to get loc works?

2) Should I use `order_book.side('side').idxmax()`

And why im getting `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable` there

3) Is there another way of doing it?

---

I checked the hidden spaces.

```
order_book.columns
Index(['id', 'price', 'side', 'size', 'symbol'], dtype='object')
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The problem with loc was here. 
`df2 = order_book.loc[~(order_book["size"] > 50) & ~(order_book["side"] == "Buy")]`

Removed `~` and `inplace = False`

So
`df2 = order_book.loc[(order_book["size"] > 100) & (order_book["side"] == "Buy")]`

Used `order_book.loc[order_book[order_book.side == 'Buy'].index[0],'price']` for 2nd question